# Esempi di uso del termine "supercazzola"

Tags: word-usage, neologism

Su questo [sito web](https://www.dailybest.it/musica/francesco-gabbani-sanremo-significato/) si può leggere la parola "supercazzola" in una critica a una canzone del Festival di Sanremo:

> Una **supercazzola** simil filosofica che condanna la società occidentale senza capire perché
>
> Se già il pezzo precedente tirava in ballo sia gli inni del comunismo italiano tipo *Avanti popolo*, sia gli *Amen* della Chiesa romana, questa volta si invola in **supercazzole** tipo asceta orientale, mascherate da critica sociale sulla vita di noi poveri stronzi che viviamo nel mondo occidentale, di cui peraltro ci risulta Carrara faccia ancora parte.

Su [Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercazzola) ho imparato che si tratta di un neologismo che ha il significato di

> una frase priva di senso logico composta da un insieme casuale di parole reali e inesistenti, esposta in modo ingannevolmente forbito e sicuro a interlocutori che pur non capendo alla fine la accettano come corretta.

Posso cogliere il senso, ma il mio problema è che non riesco a capire del tutto bene come si possa usare tale termine. Nel primo esempio della critica di Sanremo "supercazzola" pare riferirsi al testo completo della canzone, mentre invece nel secondo le "supercazzole" sembrano essere alcune frasi o espressioni presenti in un passaggio determinato. Potreste farmi alcuni esempi di uso di questo vocabolo?

Comment: Hai visto *Amici miei*, o almeno qualche scena con Tognazzi? (Sono in parte trascritte nell'articolo della Wikipedia ma vanno viste.) Si trovano anche su YouTube: una delle più famose è [questa](https://youtu.be/VWpDZPwZh40). Una definizione precisa di “supercazzora” sarebbe la cosa più paradossale del mondo.

Comment: Per precisare il commento di @DaG, la parola *supercazzola* deriva proprio dal film *Amici miei* e il modo più sicuro per capirne il significato consiste proprio nel guardare il film (che è peraltro molto bello).

Comment: Come indicato correttamente nella pagina di Wikipedia, "...Il termine è utilizzato per indicare chi parla senza dire nulla...", da quel che capisco, l'articolo citato critica l'intera canzone affermando appunto che questa vorrebbe essere densa di chissà quali profondi significati, ma in realtà non dice proprio nulla.

Comment: Daylibest?? Il sito che genera questa domanda è pura spazzatura.

Comment: Può darsi, @Bruno9779: non seguo affatto questo sito, ma si tratta di un testo che abbiamo letto nel corso di italiano che sto facendo.

Comment: @DaG: Ho cercato e ho guardato il film, e mi è sembrato molto divertente. Mi ha aiutato a capire molto meglio il senso del termine "supercazzola". Grazie mille!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Questo estratto da "*una parola al giorno.it*" fa un'interessante analisi sull'origine e l'uso del termine. Non si tratta comunque di un termine di uso comune ed ha chiari riferimenti goliardici.

***[Supercazzola](https://unaparolaalgiorno.it/significato/S/supercazzola):*** frase priva di senso pronunciata con convinzione al fine di confondere l'interlocutore.

> ***Termine coniato nella sceneggiatura del film 'Amici Miei', diretto da Monicelli nel 1975.***
>
> - Negli ultimi giorni c'è un gran parlare intorno a questa parola: infatti un primo dizionario, lo Zingarelli, nell'edizione ventura l'annovererà fra le parole della lingua italiana. È una notizia che in Toscana fa sorridere: "Amici miei" è un film di quarant'anni fa, che qui è sempre stato sulla cresta dell'onda - e la parola 'supercazzola' si usa da decenni. Fa piacere sapere che è salita alla ribalta nazionale.
> - In questo straordinario film, il personaggio forse più spassoso e intensamente drammatico è il conte Mascetti (interpretato da Ugo Tognazzi), un nobile orgoglioso ridotto in miseria. Uno dei suoi divertimenti preferiti - ma condivisi anche da altri della sua brigata di burloni - è 'fare la supercazzola'. È una presa in giro, rivolta con particolare gusto ai rappresentati di alti poteri, come pubblici ufficiali e preti: con la massima naturalezza, si dice qualcosa che è completamente privo di senso in modo da confondere la persona a cui ci rivolgiamo. Per intendersi, il primo esempio di supercazzola è quello con cui il Mascetti cerca di confondere un vigile per evitare una multa: qui sarebbe inutile una trascrizione, perché è l'interpretazione a fare tutto il gioco.
> - ***Si tratta di una parola interessante perché descrive un fenomeno molto comune e ampio, che possiamo riconoscere nel nostro quotidiano e che troviamo spesso in letteratura e nello spettacolo***. Ad esempio, nella novella "Calandrino e l'Elitropia" di Boccaccio, è una supercazzola quella che fa Maso del Saggio al credulone Calandrino quando gli descrive il Paese di Bengodi (alla domanda di quante miglia disti, risponde più di millanta, che tutta notte canta); il numero di comici che è ricorso a una supercazzola surreale per far ridere non si conta; e si può parlare della supercazzola con cui si inganna il professore distratto durante l'interrogazione, della giustificazione dell'amico che pare tanto una supercazzola, e della supercazzola burocratica che ci fanno all'ufficio chiedendo di tornare fra tre mesi (sempre per l'ISEE).
> - ***È un concetto vasto e utile, che nasce ben prima di "Amici miei"; ma forse, per comprenderlo appieno, è bene guardarsi e riguardarsi questa perla del nostro cinema***. Fra l'altro, va detto che ci sono dubbi sull'ortografia: è invalsa la forma 'supercazzola', ma pare che nella mente degli sceneggiatori dovesse essere 'supercazzora'.

Comment: Per curiosità, visto che è stato citato lo Zingarelli, ecco la voce *supercazzola*:

supercàzzola / superˈkattsola/

[comp. di *super-* e un deriv. di *cazzo*; da una battuta dell'attore U. Tognazzi nel film *Amici miei* (1975) di M. Monicelli (1915-2010) ☼ 1990]

s. f.

● (iron.) parola o frase senza senso, pronunciata con serietà per sbalordire e confondere l'interlocutore.